# How do you cast an object to a Tuple?

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, tuples

I create my Tuple and add it to a combo box:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(service, method));
```

Now I wish to cast the item as a Tuple, but this does not work:

```
Tuple<string, string> selectedTuple = 
                   Tuple<string, string>(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Don't forget the `()` when you cast:

```
Tuple<string, string> selectedTuple = 
                  (Tuple<string, string>)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
```

Comment: Thanks! I got lost in all the brackets. I'll mark your post as the best answer once the timer expires!

Comment: Or Tuple<string, string> selectedTuple = (comboBox1.SelectedItem as Tuple<string, string>);

Comment: @TYY which will hide an error if for some unexpected reason it's not a tuple. If you know something is of type T then use a cast, if you know that something might be of type T but it's valid bahavior even if it's not use as and a null test

Comment: @Rune FS Well depending on how he is using the tuple object, a check on null could make sense vs throwing an exception. Just giving him another option even though I know Cedric's answer is absolutely correct.

Comment: @TYY yes that's exactly what I state that in the case he knows it should always be the specified tuple type cast is _the_ appropriate option (because if the cast fails it is then by definition an exceptional situation) if the object could legally be something else `as`is _the_ appropriate option

Answer (score 28):

As of C# 7 you can cast very simply:

```
var persons = new List<object>{ ("FirstName", "LastName") };
var person = ((string firstName, string lastName)) persons[0];

// The variable person is of tuple type (string, string)
```

Note that **both parenthesis are necessary**. The first (from inside out) are there because of the tuple type and the second because of an explicit conversion.

Comment: I'd rather use:
var person = ((string, string)) persons[0];

Comment: Yes that's also possible but in this case you you would need to use `person.Item1` and `person.Item2` instead of `person.firstName` and `person.lastName`

Answer (score 10):

Your syntax is wrong. It should be:

```
Tuple<string, string> selectedTuple = (Tuple<string, string>)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
```

Alternatively:

```
var selectedTuple = (Tuple<string, string>)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
```