# Is the BackgroundWorker Completed event performed in background?

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker

Suppose, I  make a `BackgroundWorker` like this

```
private void RunBackgroundWorker(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //  Do something lengthy here
    // which takes a lot of time
}
private void BackgroundWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
{
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000) ; 
     BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync() ; 
}
```

I want to ask whether the contents of `BackgroundWorkerCompleted` function are executed on the "Background" thread or the main UI thread. I am asking this because, I am creating a desktop, app which  uses the database and constantly updates it's database after every few seconds

Comment: How about using async/await ?

Comment: Why don't you run it and find out.  You have the code after all.

Comment: If you want to run some code every 2 seconds you should be using a `Timer`, not a BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It executes on the UI thread. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explains:

> You must be careful not to manipulate any user-interface objects in your DoWork event handler. Instead, communicate to the user interface through the ProgressChanged and **RunWorkerCompleted** events.

That said, Servy was correct in the comments -- you should be using a `Timer` for executing code on an interval, *not* a `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: If there is a lengthy process then it should be put in a BackgroundWorker to prevent freezing the UI.

Comment: @RickHodder The `RunWorkerCompleted` event isn't for long-running processes --it's for updating the UI with the *result* of a long-running process.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `BackgroundWorker` a lot and can tell that `RunWorkerCompleted` event is **definitely** ran in UI thread. Also, you can pass the `DoWork` result to according eventArgs field and then, in `RunWorkerCompleted` take it from eventArgs to perform some UI-dependent operations with it, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939635/how-to-make-backgroundworker-return-an-object)