# C# BackgroundWorker return value after finishing

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, backgroundworker

I have this method

```
 public override SockResponse Process(Socket socket, Client client) {
        CallResponse rsp = new CallResponse();
        try
        {
            using (Transact X = client.Session.NewTransaction())
            {
                foreach (CallData call in Payload)
                {
                    DataCall dataCall = new DataCall();
                    SqlDataReader rdr = dataCall.Execute(X, call);
                    rsp.Result.Add(dataCall.BuildResult(rdr));
                    rdr.Close();
                }
                rsp.ErrMsg = "";
                X.Commit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            rsp.ErrMsg = err.Message;
            return rsp;
        }
        return rsp;
    }
```

and now I want to make it work asynchronously, and for that I've tried using `BackgroundWorker`, the new code looks like this

```
public override SockResponse Process(Socket socket, Client client)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
            delegate(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
            {
                CallResponse rsp = new CallResponse();
                try
                {
                    using (Transact X = client.Session.NewTransaction())
                    {
                        foreach (CallData call in Payload)
                        {
                            DataCall dataCall = new DataCall();
                            SqlDataReader rdr = dataCall.Execute(X, call);
                            rsp.Result.Add(dataCall.BuildResult(rdr));
                            rdr.Close();
                        }
                        rsp.ErrMsg = "";
                        X.Commit();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    rsp.ErrMsg = err.Message;
                    e.Result = rsp;
                }
                e.Result = rsp;
            });
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
            delegate(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                // First, handle the case where an exception was thrown.
                if (e.Error != null)
                {
                    Log.Logger.Error(e.Error.Message);
                }
                else if (e.Cancelled)
                {
                    // Next, handle the case where the user canceled 
                    // the operation.
                    // Note that due to a race condition in 
                    // the DoWork event handler, the Cancelled
                    // flag may not have been set, even though
                    // CancelAsync was called.
                    Log.Logger.Info("CALL process was cancelled");
                }
                else
                {
                    //  Then, handle the result
                    return e.Result; // this is where the problem is
                }
            });
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

The problem is that I have no idea on how to return the result when the `worker` is done

Comment: *Don't* use BGW, it's obsolete and your code shows why - composition is *really* hard. A simple `Task.Run(()=>Process(mySocket,myClient))` will run the method asynchronously. You can use `await` to await for the task and get the result ie `var result=await Task.Run(...);` Even better though is to modify `dataCall.Execute` to use asynchronous methods, eg `ExecuteReaderAsync`

Comment: Yes, Bgw isn't the best approach. It is sometimes the easiest though, but you've got to follow the steps. Your Try/catch completely circumvents the `if (e.Error != null)` code. And you can't return anything from the completed handler, you just store it somewhere (you're running on the main thread again).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you want to run a async code inside a synchronous method. I.e. you have a method which returns a `SocketResponse`, and want to make it asynchronous.

Well, here's the problem. Basically - you can't. Or at least it's not as simple as just making use of `BackgroundWorker`.

One way to do this is to also employ a `TaskCompletionSource`, and then wait for it to finish. The code would look like this:

```
public override SockResponse Process(Socket socket, Client client)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
        delegate (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            CallResponse rsp = new CallResponse();
            try
            {
                using (Transact X = client.Session.NewTransaction())
                {
                    foreach (CallData call in Payload)
                    {
                        DataCall dataCall = new DataCall();
                        SqlDataReader rdr = dataCall.Execute(X, call);
                        rsp.Result.Add(dataCall.BuildResult(rdr));
                        rdr.Close();
                    }
                    rsp.ErrMsg = "";
                    X.Commit();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                rsp.ErrMsg = err.Message;
                e.Result = rsp;
            }
            e.Result = rsp;
        });
    TaskCompletionSource<SockResponse> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<SockResponse>();
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
        delegate (object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // First, handle the case where an exception was thrown.
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                Log.Logger.Error(e.Error.Message);
            }
            else if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                // Next, handle the case where the user canceled 
                // the operation.
                // Note that due to a race condition in 
                // the DoWork event handler, the Cancelled
                // flag may not have been set, even though
                // CancelAsync was called.
                Log.Logger.Info("CALL process was cancelled");
            }
            else
            {
                //  Then, handle the result
                tcs.SetResult(e.Result);
            }
        });
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    return tcs.Task.Result;
}
```

This is an ugly approach - your `Process` method might be running code in a separate thread, but will otherwise take a long time to execute. The use of `BackgroundWorker` in this case is also overkill (a simple `Task` would work just the same in this case). A simplified version of the code using a `Task` would be:

```
public override SockResponse Process(Socket socket, Client client)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        CallResponse rsp = new CallResponse();
        try
        {
            using (Transact X = client.Session.NewTransaction())
            {
                foreach (CallData call in Payload)
                {
                    DataCall dataCall = new DataCall();
                    SqlDataReader rdr = dataCall.Execute(X, call);
                    rsp.Result.Add(dataCall.BuildResult(rdr));
                    rdr.Close();
                }
                rsp.ErrMsg = "";
                X.Commit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            rsp.ErrMsg = err.Message;
            return rsp;
        }
        return rsp;
    }).Result;
}
```

The above is running code in a new thread, but the `Process` method will still take a lot of time.

A BETTER approach is to make use of the `async/await` keywords and rewrite the method to return a `Task`. This MIGHT require that you rewrite your application in more places than one.

Here's how that same method might look like as an `async` method:

```
public async Task<SockResponse> ProcessAsync(Socket socket, Client client)
{
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        CallResponse rsp = new CallResponse();
        try
        {
            using (Transact X = client.Session.NewTransaction())
            {
                foreach (CallData call in Payload)
                {
                    DataCall dataCall = new DataCall();
                    SqlDataReader rdr = dataCall.Execute(X, call);
                    rsp.Result.Add(dataCall.BuildResult(rdr));
                    rdr.Close();
                }
                rsp.ErrMsg = "";
                X.Commit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            rsp.ErrMsg = err.Message;
            return rsp;
        }
        return rsp;
    });
    return await task;
}
```

HOWEVER, I already see potential issues with this: your `Process` method is an override, meaning you can't just make it return a `Task`, and you can't just slap on the `async` keyword on it either.

So, depending on how you're running the `Process` method, perhaps you can simply run that in a separate thread? Something along the lines of:

```
var socketResponse = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Process(socket, client));
```

or (if not using `async/await`)

```
var socketResponse = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Process(socket, client)).Result;
```

Also, unless you're overriding your own base class (meaning you can rewrite code to make it async), then it seems like you're working with sockets - code related to `Socket` use is, by default, based on events (Begin/End methods), and should be naturally "asynchronous".

Answer (score -1):

To return a value from `BackgroundWorker`, consider following MSDN article: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

Look down to the sample code and read following:

```
worker.ReportProgress(i * 10);
```

Or, to report a Object, consider the following StackOverflow article:
[How to make BackgroundWorker return an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939635/how-to-make-backgroundworker-return-an-object)

```
private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int result = 2+2;
    e.Result = result;
}

private void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    int result = (int)e.Result;
    MessageBox.Show("Result received: " + result.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Making use of `RunWorkerCompleted` to return a result is a valid way to... well... return results. The OP is already using it. Your suggestion to use `ReportProgress` doesn't solve the issue in the question at all.